# error in hyperledger explorer setting and start

Tags: hyperledger-explorer

I have been setting my hyperledger project.

now, fabric is running and have installed and deployed my chaincode.

but... hyperledger explorer is my problem.
I failed setup it all time.. I don't know why...

please watch my error logs and docker-compose.yaml, json files, and tell me what I wrong.

error logs

```
explorerdb.mynetwork.com    | 2021-11-01 07:28:22.178 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
explorer.mynetwork.com      | false 'ssl-certs' '/opt/explorer/ssl-certs'
explorerdb.mynetwork.com    | 2021-11-01 07:28:52.362 UTC [56] FATAL:  role "hppoc" does not exist
explorer.mynetwork.com      | error when connecting to db: { error: role "hppoc" does not exist
```

docker-compose

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
version: '2.1'

volumes:
  pgdata:
  walletstore:

networks:
  mynetwork.com:
    external:
      name: net_basic

services:

  explorerdb.mynetwork.com:
    image: hyperledger/explorer-db:latest
    container_name: explorerdb.mynetwork.com
    hostname: explorerdb.mynetwork.com
    environment:
      - DATABASE_DATABASE=fabricexplorer
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=hppoc
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
    healthcheck:
      test: "pg_isready -h localhost -p 5432 -q -U postgres"
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - mynetwork.com

  explorer.mynetwork.com:
    image: hyperledger/explorer:latest
    container_name: explorer.mynetwork.com
    hostname: explorer.mynetwork.com
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=explorerdb.mynetwork.com
      - DATABASE_DATABASE=fabricexplorer
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=hppoc
      - DATABASE_PASSWD=password
      - LOG_LEVEL_APP=debug
      - LOG_LEVEL_DB=debug
      - LOG_LEVEL_CONSOLE=info
      - LOG_CONSOLE_STDOUT=true
      - DISCOVERY_AS_LOCALHOST=false
    volumes:
      - ./config.json:/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/config.json
      - ./connection-profile:/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/connection-profile
      - ./crypto-config:/tmp/crypto
      - walletstore:/opt/explorer/wallet
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      explorerdb.mynetwork.com:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - mynetwork.com
```

test-network.json

```
{
    "name": "net_basic",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "tlsEnable": true,
        "adminCredential": {
            "id": "exploreradmin",
            "password": "exploreradminpw"
        },
        "enableAuthentication": false,
        "organization": "Org1MSP",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "construction": {
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.produce.com": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1MSP": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.produce.com/users/Admin@org1.produce.com/msp/keystore/d18828f12121b7251dcf460dc391aca47d9f82864817e91635703ca401e37244_sk"
            },
            "peers": ["peer0.org1.produce.com"],
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.produce.com/users/Admin@org1.produce.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.produce.com-cert.pem"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.produce.com": {
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.produce.com/peers/peer0.org1.produce.com/tls/ca.crt"
            },
            "url": "grpc://peer0.org1.produce.com:7051"
        }
    }
}
```

config.json

```
{
    "network-configs": {
        "net_basic": {
            "name": "net_basic",
            "profile": "./connection-profile/test-network.json"
        }
    },
    "license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```

my folder directory is

```
explorer
  ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/...
  ./connection-profile/test-network.json
  ./config.json 
  ./docker-comopse.yaml
```

Comment: Go though this may be it would be helpful. https://cmjagtap.medium.com/integration-of-hyperledger-explorer-90240b271aaa

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful for me!